# C99: Will arrays or heap-allocated buffers ever end at UINTPTR_MAX?

Tags: c, pointers, c99, intptr

Can I assume the following invariant?

```
void foo(char *buf, size_t len) {
  // "buf" points to either an array or memory allocated with malloc().
  assert((uintptr_t)(buf + len) < UINTPTR_MAX);
}
```

In a parser I am writing I want to mark certain offsets using pointers: for example I might have `char *end_of_submessage`, where `end_of_submessage` is relative to my current buffer.  But if the submessage does not end inside the current buffer, I want to use a value that is larger than any offset in the current buffer could possibly be.  So I would do:

```
void parse(char *buf, size_t len, uintptr_t end_of_submessage) {
  // Some parsing that might increment "buf"
  // ...

  // If end_of_submessage == UINTPTR_MAX, processing will not be
  // triggered even if we have processed our entire current buffer.
  if ((uintptr_t)buf >= end_of_submessage)
    process_submsg_end();
}
```

But this scheme would be thwarted if malloc() returned memory such that `ptr + len == UINTPTR_MAX`, or an array had the same property.  Is it safe to assume this will never happen?  Is it safe according to the standard?  If not, is it safe in practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only guarantee that the C standard provides is follows:

> ISO/IEC 9899:1999(E) §7.18.1.4/1
>
> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property
>   that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then
>   converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal
>   to the original pointer:
>
> ```
> intptr_t
> ```
>
> The following type designates an
>   unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void
>   can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
> uintptr_t
> ```
>
> These types are optional.

No guarantees are given about the precise content of these converted integers. In particular, given a char pointer `p`, `(uintptr_t)(p + 1) == ((uintptr_t)p) + 1` is not guaranteed to be true.

If you want to mark offsets, you should use a `ptrdiff_t` offset from another pointer, or you can simply use a pointer to mark the end. For example:

```
void parse(char *buf, size_t len, char *end_of_submessage)
{
// ...
    if (buf >= end_of_submessage)
        process_submsg_end();
}
```

If `end_of_submessage` may lie in a different buffer, you can use something like:

```
char *buf_start = buf;
// ...
if (buf_start <= end_of_submessage && buf >= end_of_submessage)
  process_submsg_end();
```

Comment: Your point is taken, but your solution unfortunately does not work for me, because the `end_of_submessage` I am trying to mark may not be in the current buffer (consider the case where there are multiple physical buffers being read for a single logical stream).  With the scheme you describe, we will run process_submsg_end() when hitting the end of this buffer, regardless of whether the submessage ends in the current buffer or not.

Comment: +1. Also note that addresses near UINT_MAX are [definitely possible in practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details).

Comment: @Josh Haberman: You could use `NULL` as your "end is in another buffer" value, and then `if (end_of_submessage && buf >= end_of_submessage)` as the test.